# Stuck on step in Lagrangian Problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

For $w,E$ column vectors, $i$ the vector of ones, and $\Sigma$ - an $n\times n$ positive definite symmetric matrix, I am trying to solve the following maximization problem:

$$
\max_{\{ w\}} \left\{ \frac{w^T E}{\sqrt{w^T\Sigma w}}\right\} \quad s.t. \quad w^T i = 1
$$
I form the lagrangian:
$$
L = \frac{w^T E}{\sqrt{w^T\Sigma w}}+\lambda(w^T i -1)
$$
$$
\frac{dL}{dw}= \frac{E(w^T\Sigma w)^{1/2} - w^TE \Sigma w (w^T\Sigma w)^{-1/2} }{w^T\Sigma w} + \lambda i \overset{\text{set}}{=} 0
$$
but I'm confused how to proceed, usually we put the derivative in terms of $w$ and use the constraint, but that's not so easy in this case, any hints?

**update** Instead solving the following problem as proposed in the comments:
$$
\max_{\{w\}} w^T E \quad s.t. \quad w^Ti=1, w^T\Sigma w=\sigma^2
$$
leads to the result:
$$
w = \Sigma^{-1} \frac{E (C\mu -B)+1(A-B\mu)}{AC-B^2}
$$
$$
\implies w^T \Sigma w = \frac{C\mu^2-2B\mu + A}{AC-B^2}
$$
where:
$$
A = E^T \Sigma^{-1}E \quad~~~~~~ B = E^T \Sigma^{-1}1 ~~~~~\quad  C= 1^T \Sigma^{-1}1
$$

Comment: $\sum$ is positive definite matrix no? If we have $w^T\sum w<0$ then the square root is not well defined. If  $w^T\sum w=0$ then the $\max$ does not exist.

Comment: @SergioParreiras yes, my mistake for not adding that, edited now

Comment: I would probably start a bit different. Fix $w^T\Sigma w=\alpha^2$ and maximize $w^TE$ subject to $w^Ti=1$ (hyperplane) and $w^T\Sigma w=\alpha^2$ (ellipsoid) with much easier Lagrangian. Then maximize the maximum/$\alpha$ with respect to those $\alpha$ that make the intersection of the hyperplane with the ellipsoid non-empty.

Comment: Another approach: you need to maximize $\gamma=\frac{w^TE}{\sqrt{w^T\Sigma w}}$ $\Rightarrow$ $w^T\Sigma w=\gamma^{-2}(w^TE)^2=\gamma^{-2}w^TEE^Tw$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $w^T[\Sigma-\gamma^{-2}EE^T]w=0$. Since $w^Ti=1$ we have $w\ne 0$, so possible $\gamma^2$ are only eigenvalues of $EE^T\Sigma^{-1}$. The corresponding $w$ must satisfy $w^Ti>0$ and $w^TE>0$.

Comment: At @A.G., I've solved the lagrangian you proposed and have a term for $\alpha^2$, I'm confused about what you mean about the intersection of the hyper plane with the ellipsoid non empty? I've updated the question to hav ethe solution of the lagrangian you proposed

Comment: In general, you would need to express $\mu$ in terms of $\sigma$, calculate the maximum as a function of $\sigma$ and maximize it, but to obtain a symbolic closed form solution may be quite messy. Please, clarify if you would like to solve the problem using Lagrangian or you are just interested in solving the problem by whatever way. There is a simple solution if you do some equivalent rewriting. (Note that your original objective function does not depend on the length of $w$, so $w^Ti=1$ is not important and can be replaced with $w^Ti>0$.)

Comment: @A.G. My goal is to show that the solution the problem is :
$$
w = \frac{\Sigma^{-1}E}{i^T \Sigma^{-1} E}
$$
i'm not really sure how to approach it if not the lagrangian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Sigma^{1/2}$ be a square root of $\Sigma$ and perform the variable change
$$
u=\Sigma^{1/2}w,\quad a=\Sigma^{-1/2}E,\quad b=\Sigma^{-1/2}i.
$$
The problem becomes
$$
\max\frac{a^Tu}{\|u\|}\quad\text{subject to } \ b^Tu=1.
$$
Since the objective function depends only on the unit vector $\frac{u}{\|u\|}$ we can replace the condition $b^Tu=1$ with $b^Tu>0$ and normalize $u$ to $b^Tu=1$ at the end. We have the following cases

**Case 1**: $a^Tb>0$ (i.e. $a$ and $b$ pointing at the same half-space). Then the maximum is clearly attained at the same direction as $a$, i.e. $u_0\|a$ and
$$
\max=\frac{a^Ta}{\|a\|}=\|a\|.
$$
Normalization gives $u_0=\frac{a}{b^Ta}$.

In the original notations: $w_0=\Sigma^{-1/2}u_0=\frac{\Sigma^{-1}E}{i^T\Sigma^{-1}E}$ and $\max=\sqrt{E^T\Sigma^{-1}E}$.

**Case 2**: $a^Tb\le 0$ (i.e. $a$ and $b$ pointing at the opposite half-spaces). In this case, to maximize the scalar product $a^Tu/\|u\|$ the vector $u$ will again try to point as close to $a$ as possible, but this time coming to the constraint $b^Tu=0$ (no normalization possible, $\|u_0\|=\infty$). Disregarding the constraint $b^Tu=1$, that is replacing it with non-strict $b^Tu\ge 0$, we will get that the best fit will be along the projection of $a$ onto the hyperplane $b^Tu=0$. It means that that is the maximum is not attained, only the supremum
$$
\sup=|\text{projection of $a$ onto $b^Tu=0$ along the normal $b$}|=
\sqrt{\|a\|^2-\frac{|a^Tb|^2}{\|b\|^2}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that your function is independent of the length of the $w$ vector. 

Since the given constraint merely normalizes $\|w\|$, the problem is effectively unconstrained.

Since the problem is unconstrained, there is no need to use the Lagrangian method.

Clear the radical by squaring of the function, then find the gradient 
$$\eqalign{
 \phi^2 &= \frac{w^TEE^Tw}{w^T\Sigma w} \cr
 \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial w} &= \bigg(\frac{(w^T\Sigma w)EE^T-(w^TEE^Tw)\Sigma }{(w^T\Sigma w)^2\phi}\bigg)\,w \cr
}$$
Setting this gradient to zero and clearing fractions yields
$$\eqalign{
\phi\,\Sigma\,w &= EE^Tw \cr
w &= \bigg(\frac{E^Tw}{\phi}\bigg)\,\Sigma^{-1}E = \lambda\,\Sigma^{-1}E \cr
}$$
Scale the result per the specified constraint
$$\eqalign{
w &= \frac{\lambda\Sigma^{-1}E}{i^T(\lambda\Sigma^{-1}E)}
  &= \frac{\Sigma^{-1}E}{i^T\Sigma^{-1}E}
}$$